# Java constructor order of calling

Tags: java

Given the following code the output is:

```
A's 1
A's 2
B's 5
```

I can't understand what is the order...

```
class A
{
    A(int number)
    {
        System.out.println("A's" + " "+ number);
    }
}

class B
{
    A aObject = new A(1);
    B(int number)
    {
        System.out.println("B's" + " "+ number);        
    }
    A aObject2 = new A(2);
}

public class myFirstProject {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B bObj = new B(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is confusing you? What order did you expect and why?

Comment: no matter where you declare a field it would be initialised before the constructor.

Comment: @Blip or to be more precise code responsible for fields initialization will be moved at start of all constructors (right after `super(..)` call).